# Traceur runtime: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Learning ES6 and have run in to the following error straight off `Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined.` Really unsure where my problem is, if anyone could help that would be great.

**main.js**

```
'use strict'

import Backbone from 'exoskeleton';
import App from './views/App';


var onDOMReady = () => {
    console.log('inside dom ready');
    window.app = new App();
}

if(document.readyState === 'complete' || document.readyState === 'interactive' || document.readyState === 'loaded' ) {
    onDOMReady();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDOMReady);
}
```

**App.js**

```
'use strict'

import Backbone from 'exoskeleton';

class App extends Backbone.View {

    initialize () {
        console.log('App: Init');
    }

    render () {
        console.log('App: Render');
    }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think they don't mean literal `super`, but rather the extends clause.

Comment: @styler I am having the same issue. How did you fix it?

Comment: @Bergi if you don't create a constructor, it's automatically assumed to be `constructor () {super()}`.

Comment: @Dodekeract: sure, but that's not where the error stems from.

Comment: @Bergi actually, yes it should be. Since the JS notices at that point that the super class is empty.

Comment: @Dodekeract: No. It does throw this error when the `class` expression is evaluated, not when the constructor is called.

Comment: @Bergi if that's true, that's super weird.

Comment: This happened to me because I tried to import and extend a class for which the base class from which I wanted to extend was missing an export in its own file. (answer converted to comment as per @stoebelj

Answer (score 8):

I got this error because I had a circular import structure. One module importing another and the other way around.

Comment: How'd you fix it?

Comment: I changed my code. To my understanding, this is the way to go with a problem like this. Not sure if there is some tricky way to allow circular references.

Answer (score 6):

`Backbone.View` may be undefined in your case. The snippet that produces this error is this,

```
if (typeof parent !== "function" && parent !== null) {
  throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof parent);
}
```

Comment: Why can it be undefined?

Comment: @Klaasvaak probably to avoid unintended effects. Things can go really damn wrong if part of the prototype is missing.

Answer (score 4):

The issue for me was because I had used

```
import { EditForm } from '../EditForm'
```

instead of

```
import EditForm from '../EditForm'
```

To make matters worse the error message was complaining about a completely unrelated component that hadn't been modified in weeks. Safe to say this one caused me some headaches. Just think back to what you recently modified and the error is likely there.

Comment: I had the other way around: I had `import Component` when it should've been `import {Component}` (`from 'react-native'`)

Comment: I saw this because I had a circular import in my module. It must have somehow returned a null value even though the import statement was technically correct.